# CSS to android Drawable xml

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

```
.Oval {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 8.6px 11px 9.4px;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 19px -19px rgba(132, 144, 194, 0.53);
  background-image: linear-gradient(216deg, #fdc194 172%, #ff6020 0%);
}
```

How to convert above css to android drawable XML

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Make a drawable resource file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="40dp" android:left="20dp"  android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#FFFFff"/>
            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp"android:gravity="left" android:left="40dp"  android:bottom="40dp" >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#f0f0f0"/>

            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item  android:gravity="left" android:left="60dp"  android:bottom="60dp" >
        <shape >
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00ffff"
                android:endColor="#0000ff"
                android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then set height and width in your view.
Please change your required colors.

Comment: Is this proper answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you are trying to create a android shape.

You have to create a new layout first. Read this documentation for better understanding.
(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

Read chapter "shape drawable" in this document for better understanding, about how to implement shape drawables:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource

After you have created a Layout you have to position a View or ImageView element.

This ImageView gets the android shape you defined as background.

[How to define a circle shape in an Android XML drawable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file)

[Position shape at exact spot on ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994403/position-shape-at-exact-spot-on-imageview)

Apart from that i would advise you to use dp (density independet pixels) instead of px and sp (scale independent pixel) in the case you use text.

[What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)